# Why output file is smaller than input by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

In order to put a mp4 file into a image, I use below command:

```
 ffmpeg -i image.png -i input.mp4
 \-filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,0,5)'" 
 output.mp4
```

As you know, `overlay` is used to position and `between` is used for time.

- The size of input.mp4(1080x1920) is **219KB**
- The size of image.png(1690 x 2856) is **356KB**

## But why the size of output file is **65KB** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Png is a lossless. Ffmpeg, by default, will use h.264 codec when creating and mp4. It is lossy, so high frequency data is removed. H.264 also has better intra frame prediction

Answer (score 0):

Probably at the time of adding it is also compressing the files.